# bitbucket down on one computer but ok on another computer

Tags: repository, bitbucket

I am having problems accessing the bitbucket website on my laptop or even update my repository through the terminal. After typing git pull, the terminal complains that the connection has timed out. This has been happening for 2 days now and I have not been able to update my repository at all.

However, on my desktop, it appears that I can access the bitbucket website (which I can't do on my laptop). Is there a way for me to reset some settings on my laptop? Both are connected to the same school network but my laptop's internet is through the wifi.

Comment: You mention a school network - are there proxy settings on the desktop that need to be added to the laptop as well?

Comment: But I never had this issue before on my laptop. I was able to connect with my laptop using the school network to bitbucket

Comment: Has something changed in the school network?